# PHP - Merging zipped and tab-delimited txt files and skipping first and last row

Tags: php

PHP - Merging zipped and tab-delimited txt files and skipping first and last row

I have several zipped files:

```
file_a.zip
file_b.zip
file_c.zip
file_d.zip
```

each containing a txt file:

```
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
file_c.txt
file_d.txt
```

and tab-delimited columns like:

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
1 description
2 header_1 header_2 header_3 header_4
3 ...
4 ...
5 ...
6 description
```

and having some description in the first and last row and column names in the second row. They have each n-rows, so they have all different number of rows. I want to merge these files to one big file having one header row but skipping all description rows. So result:

file_all.txt

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
1 header_1 header_2 header_3 header_4
2 ...
3 ...
4 ...
```

As add-on it would be great to also have a |-seperated csv file:

file_all.csv

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
1 header_1|header_2|header_3|header_4
2 ...
3 ...
4 ...
```

where | = |-delimited

Comment: Are the columns in the files identical?

Comment: Yes they are identical. I just started ... so have no example tries yet